# Change Xcode grid size on storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, grid, baseline

The storyboard on Xcode has a light blue grid on the background of 12px by 12px

Is there a way to change this value to for example 10px by 10px?

If not, is there a way to import a custom grid schema in order to better design the interface of an app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Xcode 5 the grid is gone. At least now I am sure that there is no way to set it.